# I want to postion "@formulaFiel" for alignment vertical. How can I do it in Crystal Reports 9 or 11?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to postion "@formulaFiel"  for alignment vertical.
How can I do it in Crystal Reports 9 or 11?
Thanks for you help.

Example:
Text starts centered. Then, it grows as it is in the exemplary Word (top and down).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCYaW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotate the text to `270 degrees`

Go to `format field --> Text Rotation --> Change to 270`

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's a misunderstanding. I don't want to rotate @formulaField.